# How do I change nested list in Gutenberg (Wordpress) with different numbering system?

Tags: wordpress, nested-lists, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I currently have

1. Term
2. Term

   1. Sub Term 1
   2. Sub Term 2
   3. Sub Term 3
3. Term
4. Term

What I would like are for the sub terms to be labeled 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, so it's much clearer to the reader those are sub terms within the main term.

I can't figure out how to change the listing type for the nested list.

Answer (score 0):

Indent & Outdent are the options you are looking for. These two options are for creating more-complex lists. In a way, it allows you to create lists within lists.

[image]